# How to edit EXIF data in .NET

Tags: .net, image, exif

I am writing a photo gallery/sharing website and want to (1) write EXIF data to the JPEGs stored on server, and (2) strip that EXIF data prior to writing to the output stream for display.

Is anyone aware of a dotNet library -- preferably open source -- that allows the editing (the key here is that I need to write/erase the EXIF data, not just read it) of EXIF data in image files?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check this libraries:

- [EXIFextractor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exifextractor.aspx)
- [Photo Properties](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/photoproperties.aspx)
- [A library to simplify access to image metadata](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageInfo.aspx)
- [ExifWorks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/exif_reader.aspx)
- [EXIF tag Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/EXIF_tag_Editor.aspx)

Comment: The first four items here only _read_ metadata (as does my [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) library). Only the final one in the list allows editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for a .net Standard compatible library, I highly recommend [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp).