# Adding EXIF Info to Images in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, graphics

I want to add basic exif info to images like author,camera model,date etc.Is there a way to do this using the Inbuilt classes without using other external libraries.Does the image formats like JPEG,PNG,TIFF,BMP,GIF Support all EXIF Fields.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit EXIF data in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226973/how-to-edit-exif-data-in-net)

Comment: @JoshCaswell 'without using other external libraries'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`System.Drawing` allows modifying the image properties with `PropertyItems`/`SetPropertyItem`. A sample can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/netfxbcl/thread/71d8de37-f52d-4faa-887a-793f8041110a).

But this access is quite basic and there are quite a few libraries around (see for instance [How to edit EXIF data in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226973/how-to-edit-exif-data-in-net)). So I wonder if it's worth the trouble.

After all, only JPEG and TIFF files support EXIF metadata according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format).

Comment: Allows `modify` but not `add`, it's not work if a property item that is not already exist.