# set dynamically properties of jpg image like authors,copyright in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, winforms

I want to set the properties of a jpg image. Like  its authors, copyright, comments and tag. User Uploads its image to the web site and at server side i want to set authors and other info to the image.
 

 Is there any code to set these properties dynamically in asp.net at server side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding EXIF Info to Images in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011915/adding-exif-info-to-images-in-c-sharp)